# Chat activity ad displays incorrect activity

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

The house ads for chat activity are showing that the latest activity was on the 8th.  There has been activity since, but the ads are not reflecting the new activity.

Answer (score 1):

We're tracking bugs cross meta sites now apparently.  This is completed per [this comment on AskUbuntu's meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/518/in-house-chat-ad-broken#comment-658).